# Gram-Schmidt process to Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$$ and $$q(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2$$
be vectors in $P^2$ with $pq= a_0b_0 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_2.$

Apply Gram-Schmidt orthonormal process to the set
$$ \left\{\sqrt11(x^2-1) , \sqrt11(x^2+x+2)\right\}$$

I am wondering what the inner product is. Can someone help me. Thanks.

{}{}{}

Comment: Usually in beginner classes, with polynomials the inner product is $\int f(t)g(t) dt $ but of course not always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, $<p,q>=a_0b_0+a_1b_1+a_2b_2$, otherwise the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: okay thanks! I see it doesn't really make sense that's why I was asking of the inner product. :)